# Minimum positive integral value of a

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Ibthought about a lot . but don't get any start .

can anyone provide me a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\cos(2n) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i2n} + \mathrm{e}^{-i2n}}{2}
$$
So your sum is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i2n}}{2^{n+1}} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-i2n}}{2^{n+1}}
$$
we can write
$$
\frac{e^{an}}{2^{n}} = \left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^a}{2}\right)^n
$$
so essentially you can compose your sums as geometric series, which converges if $\vert \mathrm{e}^a/2\vert <1$.